# What does class C^1 prolongation mean?

Tags: calculus

The question is as follows:

Let f(x)= |x|^3log|x|. It's true that:

a) f has a class C^1 prolongation in R

b) f has a jump discontinuity at x=0

c) 0 ∈ dom f

d) f(x)≥0, for all x ∈ (0,1)

e) f is odd

I've determined that b,c and d are all false (correct me if I'm wrong). This leaves me with a and e.
I'm pretty sure that e is false but I have no idea what class C^1 prolongation even means. This is one of the questions in a practice test from my university and I've never come across that before. I couldn't find it in textbooks or the internet. (I'm taking Calculus 1 at the moment.)

So if someone could tell me what it is and which topic to study, I'd be really grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: That means that there exists a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for every $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

From context I can tell that "has a $C^1$ prolongation in $\mathbb{R}$" means "can be extended to a $C^1$ function defined on $\mathbb{R}$". To prove that, you would need to present a continuously differentiable function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x)=f(x)$ where $x \neq 0$. I say "$x \neq 0$" because $0$ is the only place where $f$ is not already defined.

Thus the procedure for checking whether (a) is true is "define $g(0)=\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ if this limit exists, if you did that then determine whether $g'(0)$ exists, if you did that then determine whether $g'$ is continuous at $0$".

That said I have never heard the word "prolongation" actually used for this. It has always been "extension".

Comment: The word "prolongation" might be a bad translation : in French, one says *prolonger* to say "extend".

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, I suspected this might be a direct translation from some European language or another. That is usually where I have encountered terms that make English sense but not math-English sense.

Comment: The bad translation would make sense, I am at an Italian university.

Comment: But what does class ^1 mean and what topic would it be under? I'm still having difficulty finding on what these "classes" actually mean.

Comment: @Leo "Class $C^1$" means "continuously differentiable", which means it is differentiable and the derivative is continuous. Similarly $C^k$ for positive integer $k$ means "k times continuously differentiable".

Comment: @Leo $\mathcal{C}^1$ means that the function is differentiable and that its derivative is continuous : see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#The_space_of_Ck_functions).

Comment: Thanks guys, that was really helpful.